# Proving an implication by contradiction

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Let $S=((A \; and \; B) \implies C)$. Now I want to prove that $S$ is true by contradiction. In order to prove $S$ by contradiction I proceed by assuming that $S$ is false. This is my assumption in propositional logic using atomic symbols $A, B, C$: $\neg S \equiv A \land B \land \neg C$. Now I prove that $\neg A$ is true based on my assumption that $B \land \neg C$ is true. But now I have a contradiction. I assumed $A$ to be true, however, I just showed that $\neg A$ is also true. Hence I proved that the statement $S$ is true. However, I am unsure if this proof is valid / sound. Could you please explain, why the proof I described above is indeed valid or invalid.

Comment: Your argument is valid. I think a more natural way to think about it is that you're proving $S$ by assuming the premises $A$ and $B$ and then proving the conclusion $C$ by contradiction.